# Help getting this command to work on minecraft 1.8.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Profession:0,CustomName:NeverWinter Trader,CustomNameVisable:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"381",Count:8,Damage:0},sell:{id:"264",Count:5}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"262",Count:2,Damage:0},sell:{id:"345",Count:1,Damage:0}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"stick",Count:2},buyB:{id:"arrow",Count:2},sell:{id:"clock",Count:1}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"redstone",Count:6,Damage:0},sell:{id:"310",Count:1,Damage:0}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"redstone",Count:8,Damage:0},sell:{id:"311",Count:1,Damage:0}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"redstone",Count:7,Damage:0},sell:{id:"312",Count:1,Damage:0}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"redstone",Count:4,Damage:0},sell:{id:"313",Count:1,Damage:0}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"potion",Count:1,Damage:8235},buyB:{id:"nether_star",Count:1,Damage:},sell:{id:"384",Count:64}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"266",Count:1,Damage:0},buyB:{id:"ender_eye",Count:1},sell:{id:"383",Count:5,Damage:100}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"122",Count:10,Damage:0},buyB:{id:"diamond_block",Count:1},sell:{id:"120",Count:12}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5,Damage:0},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1,Damage:1}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5,Damage:0},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1,Damage:2}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5,Damage:0},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1,Damage:3}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5,Damage:0},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1,Damage:4}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"322",Count:30,Damage:0},sell:{id:"322",Count:64,Damage:1}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"133",Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:"122",Count:1,Damage:0}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"stick",Count:1},buyB:{id:"redstone",Count:2},sell:{id:"diamond_sword",Count:1,Damage:0}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:"116",Count:1,Damage:0}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"diamond_sword",Count:1,Damage:0,sell:{id"golden_sword",Count:1,Damage:0,tag:{display:{Name:Herobrine's Sword},ench:[{id:16,lvl:2},{id:21,lvl:8}],Unbreakable:true}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:redstone,Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:diamond_pickaxe,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:35}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:redstone,Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:diamond_axe,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:35}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"276",Count:1,Damage:0},buyB:{id:"snow",Count:28},sell:{id:"276",Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:50,lvl:1},{id:21,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:3},{id:16,lvl:8},{id:20,lvl:5}],display:{Name:NeverWinter Sword,Lore:["A NeverWinter Sword Created By The NeverWinter God Knight's"]}}}},]}}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  What error do you get when you try to use it?

Comment: unbalanced square brackets [] but that's not the problem

Comment: its saying data tag parsing failed unbalanced square brackets []

Comment: "but that's not the problem" - that is definitely one of the problems, though there appear to be many.

Comment: yes but I don't know coding very good

Comment: what if its the end ones at the end of the command

Comment: that I don't know if I need to put more at the end of the command or delete some :=(

Comment: and im running a minecraft server for minecraft 1.8.8

Comment: @user139359 Please stop adding multiple comments unless you actually have new information to add.

Comment: You can edit your question. unbalanced square brackets [] means that there is a pair of [] with the ] missing. When I get problems when programming, I go through the error messages one by one and fix it.

Comment: I don't see how this question is unclear. It's a low-quality, zero-research "debug this giant command", sure, but it's clear what the asker wants, to find the errors in their command.

Answer (score 6):

> CustomName:NeverWinter Trader
> Name:NeverWinter Sword
> Name:Herobrine's Sword

Strings with spaces need quotation marks around them.

> CustomNameVisable:1,

Visible is spelled incorrectly here, it should be `CustomNameVisible`.

> {ench:[{id:35}},

You need to close the square brackets around the enchantment list.

> Damage:}

You must specify a number after `Damage:`, or just `Damage:` out.

> id"golden_sword",

A `:` is needed between `id` and `"golden_sword"`.

I fixed those errors, and a bunch of unbalanced brackets, and got the following working command:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Profession:0,CustomName:"NeverWinter Trader",CustomNameVisible:1,Offers:   {Recipes:[      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"381",Count:8,Damage:0},sell:{id:"264",Count:5}},       {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"262",Count:2,Damage:0},sell:{id:"345",Count:1,Damage:0}},      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"stick",Count:2},buyB:{id:"arrow",Count:2},sell:{id:"clock",Count:1}},      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"redstone",Count:6,Damage:0},sell:{id:"310",Count:1,Damage:0}},     {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"redstone",Count:8,Damage:0},sell:{id:"311",Count:1,Damage:0}},     {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"redstone",Count:7,Damage:0},sell:{id:"312",Count:1,Damage:0}},     {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"redstone",Count:4,Damage:0},sell:{id:"313",Count:1,Damage:0}},     {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"potion",Count:1,Damage:8235},buyB:{id:"nether_star",Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:"384",Count:64}},       {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"266",Count:1,Damage:0},buyB:{id:"ender_eye",Count:1},sell:{id:"383",Count:5,Damage:100}},      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"122",Count:10,Damage:0},buyB:{id:"diamond_block",Count:1},sell:{id:"120",Count:12}},       {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1}},      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5,Damage:0},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1,Damage:1}},        {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5,Damage:0},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1,Damage:2}},        {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5,Damage:0},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1,Damage:3}},        {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"gold_nugget",Count:5,Damage:0},sell:{id:"skull",Count:1,Damage:4}},        {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"322",Count:30,Damage:0},sell:{id:"322",Count:64,Damage:1}},        {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"133",Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:"122",Count:1,Damage:0}},      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"stick",Count:1},buyB:{id:"redstone",Count:2},sell:{id:"diamond_sword",Count:1,Damage:0}},      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:"116",Count:1,Damage:0}},      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"diamond_sword",Count:1,Damage:0,sell:{id:"golden_sword",Count:1,Damage:0,tag:{display:{Name:"Herobrine's Sword"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:2},{id:21,lvl:8}],Unbreakable:true}}}},      {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:redstone,Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:diamond_pickaxe,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:35}]}}},     {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:redstone,Count:1,Damage:0},sell:{id:diamond_axe,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:35}]}}},     {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:"276",Count:1,Damage:0},buyB:{id:"snow",Count:28},sell:{id:"276",Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:50,lvl:1},{id:21,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:3},{id:16,lvl:8},{id:20,lvl:5}],display:{Name:"NeverWinter Sword",Lore:["A NeverWinter Sword Created By The NeverWinter God Knights"]}}}}        ]   }}
```

I would recommend changing the `id`'s to their [proper item names](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Item_IDs) rather than numbers, otherwise this command will stop working in 1.9. E.G: `"322"` should be changed to `"golden_apple"`.

Comment: Kudos to you.. I was just about to post a comment with the fixed brackets but since I dont minecraft script I had no idea about the rest of the formatting :D